# BAD practice? GET with some data in headers in client to client calls

Tags: post, get, header

I have a service which is called when a page is loaded or the user interacts with the page. The call to this service is currently an Ajax GET request.

Semantically no resource is created as such, but the problem is that we now have a use case which will in edge cases cause the maximum GET URL length to be exceeded.

The usual approach to such situation is to switch from GET request to POST request, but that would require extensive reworking of the code. I know headers are intended for non request specific issues such as locale, authorization token, etc, not for passing parameters, but aside from violating the spirit of the intent of headers are there performance penalties or significant drawbacks for doing this?

Comment: do you have code?

Comment: Response to question does not require code. This is a general question.